# Stateless bitcoin daemon for server, capable of signing transactions

Tags: bitcoind, client, api, json-rpc, server

I am trying to do the following:

- Have a daemon running on a server
- That daemon exposes an API (Json, etc...)
- I can call that API from localhost with:
  1: Address From
  2: Address To
  3: Key for Address From
- The daemon creates a valid transaction using the unspent outputs, signs the transaction using the key, and broadcasts it to the network, then forgets about the key.

I don't want the daemon to store the private key (stateless) and sign transactions on-demand. The daemon should be as light as possible (if possible, use less than 256 MB of RAM).

I looked at Bitcoind but it doesn't seem to provide that kind of API, since I either need to setup the wallet with the private key beforehand (not stateless) or build the raw transaction from scratch, and I don't want to have to figure out the outputs to use, format of the raw transaction, etc...

What's the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: I wouldn't want to use any service over a network that requires transferring the private key via API.

Comment: Yes, that why I want to run a daemon on my server... Maybe I wasn't clear, but this isn't for public use.